# Why Wpf User Control is calling a method multiple times?

Tags: wpf, event-handling, user-controls

I built my own user control and placed it several time in the code (exactly 4 times). It is a Combobox and when selection is changed the method should be called. Calling method works fine. But the problem is that this method is called 4 times (number of placed UserControls).

```
<ComboBox Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding NodeFileModsVM.CompanyCodeList}" 
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding CompanyVM.SelectedComboBoxItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                      materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Company Name"
                                      Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintComboBox}"
                                      Margin="0,0,30,0">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CompanyVM.CompanySelectionChangedCommand}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ComboBox>
```

ViewModel looks like this:

```
    private string _selectedComboBoxItem;
    public string SelectedComboBoxItem
    {
        get { return _selectedComboBoxItem; }
        set
        {
            _selectedComboBoxItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedComboBoxItem));
        }
    }

    public ICommand CompanySelectionChangedCommand { get; set; }

    public CompanyViewModel()
    {
        CompanySelectionChangedCommand = new RelayCommand(action => this.CompanySelectionChanged());
    }

    public void CompanySelectionChanged()
    {
         //some code that is executed.
    }
```

What I want to achieve is to call method only once when selection is changed. After selection is changed, value in each Combobox is the same so there is no necessity to call method multiple times.

What should be changed or added here to call method only once? Some code-behind or something in ViewModel should be added maybe?

Comment: What method are you referring to? Are you setting the `SelectedComboBoxItem` property? This will cause a new `SelectionChanged` event to get raised.

Comment: I am reffering to the method that is called by `InvokeCommandAction` which is `CompanySelectionChanged()`. And `SelectedComboBoxItem` is set from ViewModel in some places. I did a test and even when the `SelectedComboBoxItem` is not set the method is still called multiple times.

Comment: The `CompanySelectionChangedCommand` gets executed for each `SelectionChanged` event. So what are you doing that causes the selection to change?

Comment: So if method is executed for each selection changed that means that it will be called for each user control that was built (in this case four times)? As I understand each user control that was built (even if it is the same type of control) will monitor if such selection took a place?

Comment: Ok. I think that the topic may be closed. I just remove multiplied controls and just left only one which is accessible from any place in the app. So the problem is solved. method is called only once.